# Oracle - Best Sentence: IN(), like, REGEXP_LIKE, otherone

Tags: oracle, performance, substring, sql-like

I'm coming back here as I again need your help!
Which of the following is the better choice?

**The question is:**
I have a table `myTable` with `['DateYYYYMMDD','field1', 'field2', 'field3', 'MyField']`  and every day someone inserts many records.

**I have to create** 2 (fast) views `myView1` and `myView2` that select records (from `myTable`) created in the last 30 days, and with different `MYFIELD` values.

**I have found some distinct simple solutions and I would like to know which is the fastest:**

**Solution1**

```
--myView1:
select field1, field2, ...., fieldn, MYFIELD
  from myTable
 where DateYYYYMMDD > sysdate -30
   and MYFIELD in ('65643L', '65643L174', '65643L8N',
                   ...
                   '6564L7174', '6564L78N','6564L78N_2O15',
                   ...
                   '6564L78N3226T2_2O15', '6564L78N8N322',
                   '6564L78N6T2', '6564L78N6T2_2O15', 
                   '6564L7-NOTT1-6T2', '6564L76T2',
                   ...
                   '6563XP8N322', '6563XP8N322_2O15',
                   '6563XP8N3226T2', '6563XP8N3226T2_2O15',
                   '6563XP8N6T2', '6563XP-NOTT1-6T2',
                   '6563XP6T2', '9563XPT1',
                   '9563XPT1_2O15',
                   ...
                   '9566UB', '9566UB_2O15',
                   '9566UB174', '9566UB8N',
                   '6566UB8N_2O15', '6566UB8N174',
                   '6566UB8N322',
                   ...)


myView2:
select field1, field2, ...., fieldn, MYFIELD
  from myTable
 where DateYYYYMMDD > sysdate -30
   and MYFIELD in ('9P26_B', '9P26_BN',
                   '9P26_8N',
                   ...
                   '9P26_8NN', '9P26_2O158N9',
                   '556_B', '556_8N',
                   ...
                   '5566NP4P', '696N65T',
                   '696N65T6T2',
                   ...
                   '696W1P_B', '696W1P_8N')
```

--solution 2

```
--myView1:
select field1, field2, ...., fieldn, MYFIELD
  from myTable
 where DateYYYYMMDD > sysdate -30
   and (MYFIELD like '656%' or MYFIELD like '956%')

--myView2:
select field1, field2, ...., fieldn, MYFIELD
  from myTable
  where DateYYYYMMDD > sysdate -30
    and (MYFIELD like '9P26%' 
         or MYFIELD like '556_%' 
         or MYFIELD like '5566%' 
         or MYFIELD like '696%')
```

--solution 3

```
--myView1:
select field1, field2, ...., fieldn, MYFIELD
  from myTable
 where DateYYYYMMDD > sysdate -30
   and (REGEXP_LIKE(MYFIELD, '^656') or REGEXP_LIKE(MYFIELD, '^956'))

--myView2:
select field1, field2, ...., fieldn, MYFIELD
  from myTable
 where DateYYYYMMDD > sysdate -30
   and (REGEXP_LIKE(MYFIELD, '^9P26') 
        or REGEXP_LIKE(MYFIELD, '^556_') 
        or REGEXP_LIKE(MYFIELD, '^5566') 
        or REGEXP_LIKE(MYFIELD, '^696'))
```

I hope that explains what I need, if there is a better solution, please suggest it! 
Thank You Very Very Much!

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use LIKE?

```
--myView1:
select field1, field2, ...., fieldn, MYFIELD
from myTable
where DateYYYYMMDD > sysdate -30
and
MYFIELD like '656%' or MYFIELD like '956%'
```

etc.

REGEXP functions are powerful but not fast.

Comment: Is a simple and good option!! i search the faster... is 'like' faster of 'IN' Sentence?

Comment: I don't know but I imagine the performance of IN vs LIKE will be roughly the same - both can use an index scan if appropriate.  LIKE is more robust if you really want all matches, since your IN list could easily be missing a value.

Comment: If this is really a time critical application where you already have problems then you could consider using a materialized view, but I would not do that if you have no performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Tony Andrews said, I would avoid the REGEXP_LIKE option because you don't need any functionality that it provides that LIKE doesn't.

Having an appropriate index is going to help you much more than switching between IN and LIKE.  Ideally you would have an index on DateYYYYMMDD, MYFIELD.  If you do, I would be surprised if the difference between IN / LIKE made any noticible difference at all with how you are using them.